# apply controller data in view by days

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am trying to create a week calendar with AngularJS, but i have troubles adding the events on the 7 boxes which are my days in the week i am viewing the calendar. I have this html layout

```
<div class="week">
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

and in the controller i got this variable `jsonEvents` which has this datas so far in the test mode.

```
$scope.jsonEvents = [
        {"event_id":"1","event_name":"Basketball","event_startdate":"2","event_stopdate":"5"},
        {"event_id":"2","event_name":"Party","event_startdate":"3","event_stopdate":"3"}
    ];
```

What i want to do is, because the first event has data from 2 to 5, to add a `<li>Basketball</li>` in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th `<ul>'s` and because the second event starts 3 and ends in 3, to add a `<li>` into the 3rd `<ul>`. Do i need a directive to do that or something? Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: Yeah seems like a pretty good candidate for a custom directive.  Since you'll want to do DOM manipulations you'll want to write it as a directive.  You can use a template but in your case I think I would probably just try building the structure in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces a list with just your items shown under the relevant days...

```
  <div ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
        <div>Day {{day}}
            <ul><li ng-repeat="data in jsonEvents | filter:onDay(day)">{{data.event_name}}</span></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And add this to your controller:

```
  $scope.onDay = function(day)  {

    return function(data) {
      return data.event_startdate <= day && data.event_stopdate >= day;
    }
  }
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/GiNJy74YGyVtVfO5zxV0